# How do I convert this jQuery script to work with jQuery.getJSON with a JSON object instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I covert this code to work with `jQuery.getJSON()` with a JSON object instead of a basic java script object. In other words I want to be able to keep 
 the way the code is but with enough changes that it uses `jQuery.getJSON()` to get a JSON object in another page instead. Here's the details what I mean.

```js
var data = {
  shop: [{
      item: "Ps3",
      cost: "$150"
    },
    {
      item: "xbox 360",
      cost: "$140"
    },
         {
      event: "Black Friday",
      date: "4-25-2018"
    },
         {
      special_guest: "John Doe",
      time: "4:30 pm"
    }
  ]
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  var z = $('.z'); // Grab class z to toggle
  var x = $('#x');
  var output = '';
  $.each(data.shop, function(index, element) {
    for(var j in element){
      output += element[j] + '<br>' ;
    }
  });
  x.html(output);
  $("button").click(function() {
    z.toggle(); // Toggle z on button click
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  color: gold;
}

#x {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.z {
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="z">
<h1>Details </h1>
<h2 id="x"></h2>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

So I need to find away to convert this JavaScript object code into a JSON object and put it on another page on it's own. And use `jQuery.getJSON()` to get this JSON object

```
var data = {
    shop: [{
            "item": "Ps3",
            "cost": "$150"
        },
        {
            "item": "xbox 360",
            "cost": "$140"
        },
        {
            "event": "Black Friday",
            "date": "4-25-2018"
        },
        {
            "special_guest": "John Doe",
            "time": "4:30 pm"
        }
    ]
};
```

I still want to be able to produce the same output visually, which uses a JSON object instead and uses jQuery.getJSON to get that JSON object. I know this might be a challenge to most of you guys but I'm interested

in the code examples suggestions you guys are willing to provide to me on how to do this. And one last thing I know my JSON code example is incorrect according to https://jsonlint.com/

So i'm aware of that.

Comment: There is no way to fetch that object from a piece of javascript with `$.getJSON`. If you had a file with **only** JSON somewhere, you could fetch that though, as `$.getJSON` is just an ajax call that gets JSON. If you want something to persist  across pageloads, there are ways to do that as well.

Comment: That's what I mean I don't want that JavaScript object on the page any more I want it instead in another page instead with a json extension. So I can use jQuery.getJSON to get that JSON object.

Comment: The JSON page shouldn't have `var data =` or `;`, it should just contain the JSON literal. That's probably why you're getting errors from jsonlint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the API that returns JSON, and then put the `$.each` loop in the callback function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var z = $('.z'); // Grab class z to toggle
  var x = $('#x');
  var output = '';
  $.getJSON("url.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data.shop, function(index, element) {
      for (var j in element) {
        output += element[j] + '<br>';
      }
    });
    x.html(output);
  });
  $("button").click(function() {
    z.toggle(); // Toggle z on button click
  });
});
```

The JSON file should look like this:

```
{
    "shop": [{
            "item": "Ps3",
            "cost": "$150"
        },
        {
            "item": "xbox 360",
            "cost": "$140"
        },
        {
            "event": "Black Friday",
            "date": "4-25-2018"
        },
        {
            "special_guest": "John Doe",
            "time": "4:30 pm"
        }
    ]
}
```

It shouldn't have the variable definition at the beginning or `;` at the end, that's a Javascript statement, not part of the JSON data. And all property names need to be quoted in JSON.

Comment: Barmar your my new hero!!! Ha ha ha thank you It works! Sorry about the way I explained this and the syntax errors but you can't blame a newbie for trying to get better every day thank you so much!